# Writing a structure that contains arrays into a binary file

Tags: c++

Im prompting the user to enter sales data, then adding that data to the struct array. Is this the way to go about it?

This is my struct:

```
struct CompanyDivision {
char name[NAME_LENGTH];
double quarterlySales[QUARTERS];};
```

This is my main

```
int main() {

const int DIVISIONS = 4;


CompanyDivision allDivisions[DIVISIONS] = {{ "North" }, { "South" }, { "East" }, { "West" }};

cout << "Please enter the sales figures for each quarter at each division: " << endl;

for (int quarter = 0; quarter < QUARTERS; quarter++) {
    cout << "\n**For quarter " << quarter + 1 << endl;
    for (int division = 0; division < DIVISIONS; division++) {
        cout << "\t" << allDivisions[division].name << " >> $";
        cin >> allDivisions[division].quarterlySales[quarter];
        while (allDivisions[division].quarterlySales[quarter] < -1) {
            cout << "Please enter a non-negative sales figure." << endl;
            cout << "\t" << allDivisions[division].name << " >> $";
            cin >> allDivisions[division].quarterlySales[quarter];
        }
    }
    cout << endl;
}
ofstream outputFile("QuarterlySales.dat", ios::binary | ios::out);
for (int i = 0; i < QUARTERS; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < DIVISIONS; j++) {
        outputFile.write(reinterpret_cast <char*> (&allDivisions[i].quarterlySales[j]), sizeof(CompanyDivision)* 4);
    }
}
outputFile.close();

system("pause");
return 0;
```

}

Is the nested for loop done correctly where each division (North,South,West,East) and there quarters(1,2,3,4) and the syntax for writing out to a binary file correct?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The `for` expressions are correct... and that's all!

- you are mixing `'\n'` and `std::endl` to output end of lines: in C++ stick to former
- you read double values from `cin` without testing that the read was correct: use `if (!cin) {...}` after reading
- a test (negated) for non-negative should be `<= -1` or better `< 0`
- `outputFile.write(reinterpret_cast <char*> (&allDivisions[i].quarterlySales[j]),` is correct for the first part (converting a pointer to double to a `char *` is valid), but the size should be `sizeof(double)` or `sizeof(allDivisions[i].quarterlySales[j])` or `sizeof(allDivisions[0].quarterlySales[0])`

But you should remember that storing binary values to a file is not portable across different architectures.